# Can anyone suggest me what this below logcat is saying?

Tags: android, runtime-error

```
04-18 10:43:01.765: I/System.out(23278): MANUAL HOURS === 9:8
04-18 10:43:01.820: I/System.out(23278): ---GpsOnOff.detectGps()
04-18 10:43:01.835: D/AndroidRuntime(23278): Shutting down VM
04-18 10:43:01.835: W/dalvikvm(23278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.security/com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40538820 is not valid; is your activity running?
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.example.security.StartInspection$3.onClick(StartInspection.java:72)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40538820 is not valid; is your activity running?
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:532)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity.showGPSOnDialog(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java:195)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity.detectGps(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java:172)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity.onCreate(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java:95)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-18 10:43:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(23278):    ... 15 more
```

**Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java**

```
  public class Colect_data_from_usr_activity extends Activity {
 Dialog dialog;
 Button cnf_exit,cnf_cancel;

 private CheckBox chk1, chk2,chk3,chk4,chk5;
 Button  btn_sbmt;
 String address="";
 String adr1,adr2;
 private int mYear;
 private int mMonth;
 private int mDay;
 private TextView edt_date,edt_time,txt_location,edt_note,txt_buildingname;
 private int mhour,mminute,msecond;

 static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
 LocationManager loc_mgr ;   
 MyLocationListener location_listener;   

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.collect_data_frm_user_layout);

    dialog = new Dialog(ActGroup.group);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.confirmexit);
    dialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='white'>Exit</font>"));

    dialog.show();

    cnf_exit=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cnf_exit);
    cnf_cancel =(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cnf_cancel);
    cnf_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    cnf_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    SimpleDateFormat time_format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    Date date = new Date();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    loc_mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    detectGps();

   /*   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strloc = bundle.getString("lctn");
    System.out.println("======>>>>" + strloc);
  */    

    addListenerOnChkIos();
    addListenerOnButton();

    txt_location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
    txt_location.setText(address);
    txt_buildingname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_Building_name);
    txt_buildingname.setText(Tracker.building_name);

    edt_note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_note);
         edt_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw_date);

      Date d = new Date();
  java.text.DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    edt_date.setText(date_format.format(date));

    edt_time=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_time);
    edt_time.setText(time_format.format(date));

      edt_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
       }
   });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    msecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    }        

 private void updateDate() {
    edt_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
           .append(mDay).append("/")
           .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
           .append(mYear).append(" "));
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
  }

   //-------------------------------------------update time---------------------//    
  public void updatetime()
  {
 edt_time.setText(new StringBuilder()
               .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
                  .append(pad(mminute))); 
  }
  private void detectGps() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("---GpsOnOff.detectGps()");
if(loc_mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
{
    trackGPS();
}
else
{
    showGPSOnDialog();
}  }

   public void showGPSOnDialog() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Settings",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(callGPSSettingIntent,55);
    }
});
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
 }


 protected void showLastKnownLocation() {

Location location = loc_mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (location == null) {
    System.out.println("LOCATION GPS NULL");
    location = loc_mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

if(location!=null)
{
    String message = String.format(
            "Last Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
    System.out.println(message);
    getAddress(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
}
else
{
    System.out.println("LOCATION NULL");
}}

   @Override  
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
detectGps();
 }

 public void trackGPS() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
showLastKnownLocation();
location_listener = new MyLocationListener();
loc_mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,location_listener);
 }

 private void getAddress(double latitude,double longitude) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.this);
    try {
        List<Address> arr =  geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
    if(arr.size() !=0 && arr != null)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    System.out.println("ADDRESSSS   "+arr.get(0).getAddressLine(i));
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    adr1 = arr.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                }else if(i == 1)
                {
                    adr2 = arr.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                }
                address += arr.get(0).getAddressLine(i)+"\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("--- GETADRES EXCEPTION");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}} 
  public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
  {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(location != null)
    {
        getAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("--- location null;");
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("GpsOnOff.MyLocationListener.onProviderDisabled()");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("GpsOnOff.MyLocationListener.onProviderEnabled()");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("GpsOnOff.MyLocationListener.onStatusChanged()");
}}

  private void CheckEnableGPS(){
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider.contains("gps")){
    //GPS Enabled
    System.out.println("PROVIDE -- "+provider);
    //  Toast.makeText(Start_hr_activity.this, "GPS Enabled: " + provider,
    //          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    //Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

 private static String pad(int c) 
  {
 if (c >= 10)
      return String.valueOf(c);
 else
      return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
 }

  //Datepicker dialog generation  
  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                         int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       mYear = year;
       mMonth = monthOfYear;
       mDay = dayOfMonth;
      updateDate();
   } 
 };

 // Timepicker dialog generation
  private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    mhour = hourOfDay;
    mminute = minute;
    updatetime();
       }
   };
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   switch (id) {
   case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       return new DatePickerDialog(this,
               mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
   case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
       return new TimePickerDialog(this,
               mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, false);
        }
   return null;
 }

  public void addListenerOnChkIos() {

chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_windowopen);
chk1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            }

        }
    });
}

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_windowopen);
    chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_dooropen);
    chk3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_employeeonsite);
    chk4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_glassbroken);
    chk5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doorbroken);

    btn_sbmt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sbmt);
    btn_sbmt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    String str_1 = String.valueOf(chk1);
    String str_2 = String.valueOf(chk2);
    String str_3 = String.valueOf(chk3);
    String str_4 = String.valueOf(chk4);
    String str_5 = String.valueOf(chk5);

    String str_dt = edt_date.getText().toString();
    String str_tm = edt_time.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("********_--------________--- "+ str_tm);

    String str_loct = txt_location.getText().toString();
    str_loct.valueOf(txt_location.getText().toString());

    String str_note = edt_note.getText().toString();
    String incidents="";

    if(chk1.isChecked())
     {
        incidents += chk1.getText().toString()+"\n";
     }

    if(chk2.isChecked())
     {
        incidents += chk2.getText().toString()+"\n";
     }
    if(chk3.isChecked())
     {
        incidents += chk3.getText().toString()+"\n";
     }
    if(chk4.isChecked())
     {
        incidents += chk4.getText().toString()+"\n";
     }

    if(chk5.isChecked())
     {
        incidents += chk5.getText().toString()+"\n";
     }

    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putString("c1", incidents);
    b.putString("date", str_dt);
    b.putString("time", str_tm);
    b.putString("lctn",str_loct);
    b.putString("note", str_note);
    b.putString("adr1", adr1);
    b.putString("adr2", adr2);
    loc_mgr.removeUpdates(location_listener);
Intent intnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), Colected_data_result_activity.class);
intnt.putExtras(b);
View view = ActGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Colected_data_result_activity", intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
ActGroup.group.replaceView(view);
//  Toast.makeText(Report.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

**Latest Logcat**

```
04-18 11:49:34.414: D/AndroidRuntime(27731): Shutting down VM
04-18 11:49:34.414: W/dalvikvm(27731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.security/com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at com.example.security.StartInspection$3.onClick(StartInspection.java:72)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity.detectGps(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java:159)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at com.example.security.Colect_data_from_usr_activity.onCreate(Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java:66)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-18 11:49:34.453: E/AndroidRuntime(27731):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: that's a lot of code. pls reduce the same only to the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a dialog from within `onCreate`; that's what's causing the cryptic exception. The window has not been created yet. Move the `detectGps` call (and the other dialog showing code) to `onStart` and it should work.

In fact, though, you should be overriding `onCreateDialog` and using `showDialog` to show the dialogs. This allows the activity to correctly manage the dialogs during the activity lifecycle events.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, but i am getting some null pointer exception on logcat.Please visit my question again,i have posted my latest logcat

Comment: @Android_user - You're getting a null pointer exception at line 159 of Colect_data_from_usr_activity.java. What line is that?

Comment: private void detectGps() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 System.out.println("---GpsOnOff.detectGps()");
 if(loc_mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
 {
  trackGPS();
 }
 else
 {
  showGPSOnDialog();
 }}

Comment: @Android_user - That's the entire method. Which is line 159?

Comment: this one if(loc_mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))

Comment: @Android_user - The only thing that can cause a NPE there is that `loc_mgr` is `null`. I see from the stack trace that you are still calling `detectGps` from `onCreate`. That's not going to work because the activity is not yet fully initialized. Override `onStart` and call the method from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28410/discussion-between-android-user-and-ted-hopp)

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, that exception is due to adding a dialog to a activity which is not running foreground.
In onCreate, that dialog constructor should be passed with context of current running activity. But, according to above code that dialog constructor having activitygroup(ActGroup.group returns activitygroup ) as argument rather than context.

If you still want to use ActGroup.group, then that dialog constructor should contain ActGroup.group.getCurrentActivity().

Comment: dialog = new Dialog(ActGroup.group.getCurrentActivity()); or dialog = new Dialog(new ActivityGroup().getCurrentActivity()); use any of these two.